# C++/CLI Generic::Dictionary Declaration Syntax

Tags: syntax, dictionary, c++-cli, declaration

I'm been curious about the declaration syntax of Collections::Generic::Dictionary
class in C++/CLI.

Normally we declare a reference in a class and initialize it:

```
public ref class CDemo {
    private: ClassA ^ m_InstanceA;

    // Why the absence of '^'.
    private: Dictionary<int, int> m_Dic;

    CDemo() : 
        m_InstanceA(gcnew ClassA()),   
        m_Dic(gcnew Dictionary<int, int>()) 
    {...}
};
```

Could someone explains please why should the '^' absent there?

What's more, if I were to use the dictionary above as a *TValue* of another dictionary,
I have to declare it like this:

```
Dictionary<T, Dictionary<T, T>^ > m_Dic;  // A '^' in the TValue parameter, which is           
                                          // normal, but same question as above,
                                          // I don't have to declare m_Dic as ^ ?
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's a bug.  Look at the generated IL for the constructor, note how two dictionaries get created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not specific to `Dictionary`. This syntax is a way to help map C++ semantics onto managed types. In general:

```
ref class A
{
   ReferenceType m_obj;
};
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
class A : IDisposable
{
  private ReferenceType m_obj;
  void Dispose() { m_obj.Dispose(); }
}
```

in C# *if* `ReferenceType` implements `IDisposable`. It is perfectly possible to write

```
ref class A
{
   ReferenceType^ m_obj;
};
```

This does not have the implicit `IDisposable` support. The other difference is that you can return a `ReferenceType^` from a method, this is not supported with just plain `ReferenceType`. For example:

```
ref class A
{ 
   ReferenceType^ m_obj;
   ReferenceType^ GetIt() { return m_obj; }
};
```

will compile,

```
ref class A
{
   ReferenceType m_obj;
   ReferenceType GetIt() { return m_obj; }  // won't compile
   ReferenceType^ OtherGetIt() { return m_obj; } // neither will this
};
```

A similar distinction is provided for automatic (stack variables)

```
      ReferenceType local;
      local.Stuff();
```

is desugared by the compiler to

```
      try {
        ReferenceType^ local = gcnew ReferenceType();
        local->Stuff();
      } finally {
        delete local; // invokes Dispose() (~ReferenceType)
      }
```

These features bring the familiar idiom of RAII to C++/CLI with managed types.

EDIT:

Yes, the Dispose method of IDisposable is analogous to a C++ destructor. If `ReferenceType` doesn't implement `IDisposable` (doesn't have a dtor), and it is the only member, `A` will also not implement `IDisposable` (not have an implicit dtor). In C++/CLI you implement `IDisposable` by providing a dtor (for managed types).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you explain the second point again?

"in C# if ReferenceType implements IDisposable. It is perfectly possible to write..."

The IDisposable here is same as the dtor of C++/CLI ?
What if the C# type doesn't implement the IDisposable interface?